# C# asp:RadioButton Not Displaying Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

My RadioButtons aren't being displayed properly and I can't figure out why.
When the HTML is rendered it replaces the text with '*****'

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblActive" runat="server">Active?</asp:Label></b><span class="Data">
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnActiveYes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="Active" Text="Yes" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnActiveYes_CheckedChanged"></asp:RadioButton>&nbsp;
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnActiveNo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="Active" Text="No" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnActiveNo_CheckedChanged"></asp:RadioButton></span>
```

[image: RadioButton Screenshot]

Here's the rendered HTML from the browser
[image: Rendered HTML]

I've tried overriding it by adding a label for the ID in my code however it still shows the asterisk

`<label for="rbtnActiveYes">Yes</label>`

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this problem exist on all pages in your project, or just this page? It looks like some sort of "hide password" function is (too) active

Answer (score 0):

Use RadioButtonList instead of 2 radio buttons